# How to get status of phone Cisco Jtapi

Tags: java, telephony, cisco, jtapi, cisco-jtapi

I wanted to know how to get the status of a phone using Jtapi. I am familiar with the addressChangedEvent and terminalChangedEvent methods of address and terminal observers. However, I am having a hard time trying to get the status of an address (phone). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use javax.telephony.callcontrol.CallControlTerminal

This provides functions like : getAdresses, and getTerminalConnections

From an Address you can get a Conncetions and a connection is bound to a call and this provides a state.

A TerminalConnection also provides a state

```
    Address adr[] = terminal.getAddresses();
    int callState = adr[0].getConnections()[0].getCall().getState();
    TerminalConnection tcs[] = terminal.getTerminalConnections();
    int conState = tcs[0].getState();
```

getConnections and getTerminalConnection may retun null!

Comment: What about something like                                                               CiscoAddress adr = (CiscoAddress) provider.getAddress("phone number") Would adr.getState() give the state of the phone?

Comment: This may give the state of the phone (what ever that means in CISCO world, see CISCO Docs). I prefer using portable features as long as possible.